# Can I make spaces between HTML tags not screw up relative positioning?

Tags: html, css, spacing, css-position

There is a line break between two `<img>` tags, and they are indented in the document for nice-formatting.

But I'm using relative positioning and z-order to place one image (part of the layout) overtop of another.

I have something like this

```
<img style="position: relative; z-index: -1;" width=a height=b>
<img style="position: relative; z-index: 0; left: -a" width=x height=y>
```

the line break after the first `<img>` tag adds a space, and then when I set the relative left position of the second `<img>` tag, that space is taken into consideration and it's set just a little bit to the right of the first image.

I don't want to put them on the same line, making the lower image tag a background isn't an option (it has to be sized), and fiddling with the relative position is out of the question (I'm assuming spaces will be different sizes on different browsers/systems).

Can I make this work?

### edit -- more info

The spacing is throwing off the relative positioning. Is there no way to just position them absolutely, but to the `left` and `top` of another element, which has static positioning?

anyways, the layout in its current state has an image overlapping another image. The overlapped image is a div background and the piece of layout is an image in the div.

I need to change the overlapped image when a link is clicked (a thumbnail of an image is clicked, and a larger version appears in the overlapped image). But the images are all different sizes, larger than the default div background image. I can't resize a div background so it has to be an image. But the problem is getting one image to overlap another. They want me to also fade between images, so I need two images, stacked on top of each other (with the top one fading in and out to a bottom one), plus the edge of the layout over top of those.

I don't know how to accomplish this any other way

Comment: Okay, I'm really confused. First: you could have 10 hard returns between the images as far as the code goes, it won't make the images move farther apart. The problem isn't with the indentation or with the hard return. the problem is that one image comes after the other one in the actual DOM (they are loaded one after the other). So you could have your HTML have no line breaks and be one long line, you'll still have this issue. Secondly, what is your actual goal? I see your comment where you say "this makes them on top of each other, not in the same spot." What does "the same spot" mean?

Comment: You want the smaller image to be inside the larger image? so that the larger image is really a background for the smaller image?

Comment: The same spot meant exactly the same spot, with both of them being `<img>` elements (no backgrounds). My problem was that a line break translates to a space and how I was doing it would only work if there was *nothing* between the two tags. But the hard return would render to a space. But I was approaching the problem wrong, how I have it built now, it doesn't matter at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What is that z-order there? its z-index. 
And how will line break within design improve anything. 
As i see things z-index and line breaks in website layout/design are the last things you should use. What you need is proper margins and paddings. Also read about negative margins before you start using z-index.

Check these out :
http://www.barelyfitz.com/screencast/html-training/css/positioning/
http://www.elated.com/articles/css-positioning/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/07/27/the-definitive-guide-to-using-negative-margins/
http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/05/01/css-float-theory-things-you-should-know/

Comment: Well the easyest way to make it work would probably remove layers and make first image position absolute, and 2nd relative. Then give the 2nd one correct margins. 

If you havent already, then get firefox and download firebug - www.getfirebug.com. With it you can play around with layout really nice.

Comment: I can't make the first one positioned absolute, it's part of a layout which can change. I guess I can just position one as static, and then use javascript to position the other ones accordingly?

Comment: javascript is also overcomplicating things. You haveto consider people who have turned javascript of and always use javascript unobtrusively. 

<quote>the layout in its current state has an image overlapping another image. The overlapped image is a div background and the piece of layout is an image in the div. </quote>

so first image is background of div element and overlaping image is element after the div? Plus all the following text says that you need something like Slimbox/thickbox/etc. Just play with their css and implement it into your design?

Comment: well, I need javascript for the feature to work... and it's not thickbox/slimbox etc--three images have to be stacked /right/ on top of each other. Also, the first is a div background, and the second is an image within the div. But I need to change the div background into an image, and then add another image of the same size underneath it.

Comment: Ah so it will be stack of three images? image below div, div, and image above div? And images probably have some alpha layers..
then you definately need z-index. What i dont understand though is why you cant use absolute positioning. Absolute does not always mean when related to whole page. Look the first link and example 4. 
If i could see the wireframe of image think i could help you more. right now im just extremely puzzled and sleepy :)

Comment: ah, I understand. Well, it's a div containing three images, as shown in my answer to my question.
However if all three images in the div are positioned absolute, then the rest of the page ignores the div they are in. I suppose there has to be at least one static thing in it. It works good, sorry for all the grief, I was in a hurry.

Comment: sorry this is so old, I'm going through my questions which I have not accepted an answer for. Using absolute positioning worked perfectly, though I didn't catch on right away. I'm too used to C and assembly! Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is what ended up working for me:

I just placed the top image (a part of the layout, sort of an edge which creeps over onto the image in one part) in the layout like normal (left aligned in a statically sized `div`, which is in the center of the page).

Then I made the other two absolutely positioned, at just 0,0 (but it doesn't matter where).

```
<center>
    <div style="width: 686">
        <img id="ed" src="./edge.jpg">
        <img id="bg" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -2;">
        <img id="fg" style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; z-index: -1;">
    </div>
</center>
```

then using a bit of JavaScript, I fixed the position of the other two images:

```
function fixImages() {
    var imageEdge = document.getElementById('ed');
    var foregroundImage = document.getElementById('fg');
    var backgroundImage = document.getElementById('bg');

    foregroundImage.style.left = imageEdge.style.left;
    foregroundImage.style.top = imageEdge.style.top;

    backgroundImage.style.left = imageEdge.style.left;
    backgroundImage.style.top = imageEdge.style.top;
}
```

it might *not* be the best way to do it, but it works and I'm being pressured for this project to be finished, so it will have to do for now.

Answer (score 0):

Carson,

The `<center>` tag is deprecated.(to my knowledge).  I believe if you since you've set the div to width:686px, you can use margin:0 auto.

For what I believe is the effect you're attempting, maybe this [jQuery slideshow tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/building-an-auto-scrolling-slideshow-that-works-with-and-without-javascript/) will help.

It uses an unordered list made horizontal, makes only one list visible at a time, and scrolls through them automatically.  You can change the sliding feature to 'fade' in the slideshow.js like so:

```
 $slideshow = {
        context: false,
        tabs: false,
        timeout: 5000,      // time before next slide appears (in ms)
        slideSpeed: 500,   // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms)
        tabSpeed: 500,      // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms) when clicking through tabs
        fx: 'scrollLeft',   // the slide effect to us
```

e

change the above fx:'scrollLeft' to fx: 'fade' so it'll look like this:

```
$slideshow = {
        context: false,
        tabs: false,
        timeout: 5000,      // time before next slide appears (in ms)
        slideSpeed: 500,   // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms)
        tabSpeed: 500,      // time it takes to slide in each slide (in ms) when clicking through tabs
        fx: 'fade',   // CHANGED TO 'FADE'
```

Also, after building this, use your images as list items, and replace the pagination texts in the tutorial to the relevant image thumbnails.

You can tinker with the speeds & time out & it also works well without javascript enabled.

Also, if this doesn't help you achieve the effect you want, can you make a sketch?  The use of 'overlapping' is a bit confusing.

Answer (score -1):

apply `display: block;` to your `img` tags' styling.

Comment: this caused them to appear on top of each other rather than in the same spot